# Formatting dates in Argo

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj

In order to get a date like `20201008` in Argo, what's the best way of formatting a date in a template?

This seems to work but is fairly verbose, and creating the string for something like `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` is going to get very difficult for others to read.

```
 "{{workflow.creationTimestamp.Y}}{{workflow.creationTimestamp.m}}{{workflow.creationTimestamp.d}}"
```

I think these are the relevant docs: https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/docs/variables.md. I tried `"{{workflow.creationTimestamp.Ymd}}"` but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Argo 3.1, some templating is supported, such that this now works:

```
"{{=sprig.date('20060102', workflow.creationTimestamp)}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way (inside of the template) to make this more concise.

There is a [hard-coded list](https://github.com/argoproj/pkg/blob/50e2680bec730dc985bb2e50d02c1d383caa0145/strftime/strftime.go#L12) of supported time format characters. [For each character in that list, a global parameter is populated](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/cac10f1306ae6f28eee4b2485f802b7512920474/workflow/controller/operator.go#L463-L470), along with the base `workflow.creationTimestamp` variable. There is no dynamic reading or processing of the characters after `workflow.creationTimestamp.`.

Since the templating is based on Jinja2, there has been [discussion](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/issues/1293) of more robust string templating support. But various complications have stalled that discussion. (The Argo team uses "thumbs up" counts to prioritize issues, so it might help to give that issue a bump.)

I'm sure you've thought of this, but for the sake of completeness: if you are using the variable in a pod you could send the full `workflow.creationTimestamp` and do some runtime manipulation to get the format you want.

Finally, you can [submit an issue](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/issues) to request the feature. Even if they decide not to implement it, the example would make the discussion about Jinja2 templating a bit more concrete for the developers.

Comment: Thanks for the full and thoughtful response. FYI there's some discussion continuing here: https://github.com/argoproj/argo/issues/1293